# How can I print two separate cut jobs on hp latex with onyx rip?

Tags: print-design, cutter

HP Latex 360, Onyx RIP software, I have a summa plotter cutter machine.

What I have found is, as I can only fit a certain size width in my plotter I have to cut down , or make sure my print file is the correct size. However, this means i end up with half a sheet of vinyl wasted on my printer. When i have duplicated the jobs or even loaded as separate jobs, it combines the barcode strip , so how can I get to create two separate barcode sections of the two jobs so that i can cut it down the middle and load them separately into my plotter... there must be a simple solution I'm missing surely people don't waste loads of vinyl?!